# How to proper set java in windows?

Tags: java

I have installed java. I want work in cmd, so I write javac name_of_file.java. Javac was unrecognize, i must add path to java. I was searching of "javac" on computer. I was copy that adress and  add to path.

Now, javac work, but when i write: java name_of_file I have got that comunicate:

```
 C:\Users\Naukowy>java version
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ver
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: version
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: version.  Program will exit.
```

Next I wrote : java version And I have got the same message.

How can I make that will proper works?

```
 C:\Users\Naukowy\Desktop\plik xml>javac XSDValidate.java

C:\Users\Naukowy\Desktop\plik xml>java XSDValidate
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: XSDValidate :
 Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 Could not find the main class: XSDValidate.  Program will exit.

C:\Users\Naukowy\Desktop\plik xml>
```

Comment: Is `version` the name of your class?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your problem exactly is, so I'll try to explain all possible problems that I see here ;):

Do you want to find out the Java version? Use

```
java -version.
```

Compared to that,

```
java version
```

tries to start a Java class called version, which doesn't exist obviously.

If you want to compile a .java file, use

```
javac file.java
```

That will result in a file.class class file to be created. To run that:

```
java file
```

*Thanks to T.J. Crowder for the correction. Don't try java file.class, but use java file.*

**Update**
Your major/minor version issue is a totally different issue. See [How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0) for more information.

Comment: I just do it yes? javac a.java  java a And I have that comunicate what I wrote what can I do? Where I wrote I use java file.class? Where ?

Comment: Please give us your entire console input and output. I don't understand what exactly you are doing and where the problem is.

Comment: I add now what I do step by step

Comment: That's a completely different issue now. See my updated answer.